# Create vmdk from within VBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vmdk

I have Oracle vm Virtual Box (ver 5.0.0 )virtual machine setup on Windows 7 Enterprise machine, running, and doing what I expected it to do. It is necessary to do the same setup on a few other workplaces. The setup process was tedious and I'd like to avoid it doing again. Is it possible (at least theoretically) to create a vmdk file having all the setting, files, etc being within the running virtual machine and afterwards using this vmdk file with other installations?
I have read about vmkfstools, but I'm still none the wiser whether my intentions are at least feasible.
The virtual machine is 
Linux 3.13.0-128-generic #177-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 11:41:08 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I didn't occur to me (being new to VBox technology the idea simply didn't come into my mind) that all changes I have done to the running machine are permanently stored into the .vmdk files used (or created) initially. So the question happened to be useless. VBox's doing automatically what I wanted to do specifically and manually.
It is sill not quite clear to me what are the steps I should follow if I want to move that vmdk file(s) to some other virtual machine.